# how to link first list view to second list view android.view

Tags: android, listview

I created one list view with items so here when i press one item(item number one)it 
   has to be open another list view item list.

How can we create that type of list view item  and please tell what type of item it calls

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list );
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
         try {
          DisplayM.main();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // if (ViewClass.theEnd)
        // your_array_list.add(ViewClass.methods);  
    int lst = 0;
    for(int  i=0; i<lst; i++)
    {
    }

    }
```

Comment: you need to open second row of same listview

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list );
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> otherArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_other_array_list );
            otherlist.setAdapter(otherArrayAdapter);
        }
    });
```

Comment: ram is talking about "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" this

Comment: don't no sir it is asking 15 reputations to vote i am new to this site